# Что делает эта функция <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>?

Tags: yii, yii2

Я установил **Yii2**, и в файле *view/layouts/main.php* увидел эту функцию - `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`
так же я прочитал что она генерирует какие-то  мета-теги от межсайтовой подделки запроса. Но не понятно что именно она делает, как защищает и в каких именно страницах HTML, она нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csrfMetaTags() просто вставляет в страницу два мета-тега: csrf-param и csrf-token. Понадобиться это может когда придется что-то аяксом заслать, без токена в запросе Yii2 по дефолту просто его не обработает, вернув 400 ответ. Эти токены так же автоматом вставляются во все формы, создаваемые средствами фреймворка в виде hidden поля. Поэтому если будете создавать форму в обход хелперов - тоже придется вставлять туда токен через getCsrfToken().

Ну а про саму csrf-атаку информации в сети вроде вагон. Вкраце это защита пользователя от совершения каких-то действий на вашем сайте без его согласия. Т.е. если пользователь у вас авторизован, то при заходе на сайт взломщика его могут аяксом или каким-то видом редиректа заставить выполнить нужный запрос на вашем сайте и без проверки реферера или токенов этот запрос успешно выполнится.